# How to automate a msi installation that opens a customization window

Tags: c#, automation, windows-installer, exe

I’m trying to automate the installation of a program that my company created.

The installation file is an msi, but the issue is that the installer opens a customization window, and when I run the msi with /qn or similar switches, the window still opens.
I opened the msi with Orca and found that the customization window is an exe that the installer runs. I tried using c# UIAutomation functions, but they don’t work on the customization window.
How can I automate this?

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic no no if your software is aimed to be silently installed by enterprise customers. I made a [full list of do's and don't](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/software-packaging-best-practices.html#testing-software-installation) and having UI custom actions during a silent installation is against the recommendations.

The GUI is probably triggered by a custom action scheduled in the Installer Execute Sequence, as only custom actions from that sequence run when an MSI is installed with **/qn**.

So first, you need to move that custom action under InstallUISequence, so it will show the customization GUI only when the users install the app with full UI.

For silent installs, it is recommended to build another [custom action](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/qa-c-sharp-ca.html) that can accept command line parameters or a config file as command line parameters, process those params, and save them wherever your application needs them. This is most likely what the customization GUI does too.

The links above show how to include the custom action into a setup built with Advanced Installer, but the same custom action DLL can be included into a setup built with Visual Studio too.